# Difference Between NavigationService.Navigate and (Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame).Navigate in windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8

what is difference between 

    `(Application.Current.RootVisual as 
        PhoneApplicationFrame).Navigate(new Uri("/FeedBackMessageBox.xaml", 
        UriKind.Relative));`

and

    `NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/SecondPage.xaml",
        UriKind.Relative));`

in windows phone8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `(Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame).Navigate(new Uri("/FeedBackMessageBox.xaml", UriKind.Relative));`, then you are reffering to [Frame.Navigate() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ms602275).

When you use `NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/SecondPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));` then you reffer to [NavigationService property of a Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.controls.page.navigationservice%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Both methods will do the same and as [Remarks at MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice%28v=vs.105%29.aspx):

> When navigating from within the frame, you use the navigation methods on the frame. The Frame class contains many of **the same methods** and properties as the NavigationService class.